# Função DELPHI para PHP

Tags: php, delphi

estou reprogramando um sistema de um cliente e preciso converter uma função em Delphi para o PHP para concluir uma etapa do sistema e estou com dificuldades quanto a isso... poderiam me dar um help.. agradeço desde já.. segue o código abaixo que precisa ser convertido para o PHP:

```
Function CalcRegistro(Codigo: String): String;
Var vCod: Extended;
    vCnt, vAsc: LongInt;
    vStr: String[128];
Begin
    vCod:= 0;
    vStr:= Copy(Codigo + RepeatStr(' ',128), 1, 128);
    For vCnt := 1 to 128 do
    Begin
        vAsc:= Ord(vStr[vCnt]);
        vAsc:= (vAsc + (128-vCnt));
        vCod:= vCod + Power(vAsc,6);
    End;
    Result:= FloatToStrF(vCod, ffFixed, 16, 0);
End;
```

Comment: PHP é basicamente não tipado. Boa parte disso acaba que não é traduzido para o PHP. Já tentou fazer alguma coisa?

Comment: O problema está justamente com estas funções do Delphi, "Ord" e "Power".. nunca trabalhei com o delphi...

Comment: A função que esta tendo dificuldade esta em `System.Math`, no seu exemplo estão usando Funções básicas do Delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dois detalhes: não me lembro de existir uma função "Repeatstr" no Delphi, então mudei para "stringofchar". O Delphi tem um índice inicial (em strings) em 1, ao contrário do PHP onde o índice inicial é 0, então precisei ajustar isto. Segue a função em PHP:

```
function CalcRegistro($Codigo)

  {

    $vCod=0;

    $vStr= substr($Codigo . str_repeat(' ',128), 0, 128);

    for ($vCnt = 0; $vCnt
      {

      $vAsc= ord(substr($vStr,$vCnt,1));

      $vAsc= ($vAsc + (128-$vCnt-1));

      $vCod= $vCod + pow($vAsc,6);

    }

  return substr(str_replace(",","", number_format($vCod)),0,16);

}
```